# Why most local addresses are like 192.168.xxx.xxx?

Tags: networking, ip-address

Is it some standard/practice or technical requirement which force network engineers to use this IP address pattern?

Comment: All private addresses **are not** 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: This is a site for *professionals*. This is such an incredibly basic question that any professional should know it.

Comment: Ok, lesson learned

Answer (score 11):

[RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) establishes ranges for private address space.

- 192.168.0.0/16
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 10.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 6):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of 'reserved' ranges as defined by the IETF. 192.168 is the standard used by linkysys and many other vendors for their home networking requirement. But there is no requirement for this specific subnet for home networks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses